# How to update *.ts (for Qt Linguist) files in CMake Qt project?

Tags: qt, localization, cmake, qt-linguist

I found how to use .ts files in CMake:

```
SET(TRANS localization/en_en.ts)
QT5_ADD_TRANSLATION(QM ${TRANS})
```

(and added to executables).

And when i run lupdate from the Qt menu I've got the following: `lupdate warning: no TS files specified. Only diagnostics will be produced.`

So how can I update *.ts  for a simple CMake project?

Comment: @ЕвгенийДружинин please check here https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/linguist-creating-ts-files.html

Comment: This correctly for Qt6, but I use Qt5. Can you help me with Qt5?

Comment: @ЕвгенийДружинин try this? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtlinguist-cmake-qt5-create-translation.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following:

```
file(GLOB TS_FILES "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.ts")

qt5_create_translation(QM_FILES
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
    ${TS_FILES}
    OPTIONS -source-language en_US -no-obsolete)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OS_BUNDLE} ${SOURCES} ${RESOURCES} ${QM_FILES})
```

Note, that `QM_FILES` should be in the list of sources for the target (`${PROJECT_NAME}` here).

Comment: I have the same problem, but your answer does not help me. Can you answer again?